# Studying in Canada and working in the United States

Tags: usa, working-visas, immigration, h1-visa

Does the USA allow students with non-US degrees to work under any visa?

Some background: I am an Indian citizen pursuing my master's in Canada in marketing. Once I am done with my master's, would it be possible to apply for a job in the States? If so, under which category apart from the H1B visa?

Also, my partner is currently in the US on an H1-B. Does this have any difference/advantage in this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

> Does the USA allow students with non-US degrees to work under any visa?

Yes.  Employer-sponsored work visas do not depend on the source of the sponsored worker's education.

H-1B is the most common such visa, but there are others that apply, for example, to intra-company transfers.

> Also, my partner is currently in the US on an H1-B. Does this have any difference/advantage in this scenario?

Not a whole lot.  If you marry, you might be able to get an H-2 visa.  If you do, you would have to apply separately for employment authorization.  There is some disagreement about whether such authorization should be allowed, so it's not something you should count on.